# Save old parameter in function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I create an instant messenger. My function *cliked(thread)* allows me to click on a discussion and view this discussion. The user can not have more than 2 chat windows open at the same time.
So when two chat windows are open (*this.threadService.windows.length === 2*), I have to close the first window to display the new window.

I must then save this first window in a variable, in order to enter it as a parameter of my function *closeOldThread(oldThread)*

```
clicked(thread: Thread): void {
 this.newWindow = true;

 let oldThread: Thread;
 if(this.threadService.windows.length === 2) {
   this.closeOldThread(oldThread);
 }
 if (!this.thread.isOpen) {
   thread = this.chatService.openThread(thread);
   this.chatService.setCurrentThread(thread);
   this.thread.isOpen = true;
 }
 oldThread = thread;
}
```

////

```
closeOldThread(thread: Thread): void {
 let index = this.threadService.windows.indexOf(thread);
 this.threadService.windows.splice(index, 1);
 this.thread.isOpen = false;
 this.newUser = false;
 this.newWindow = false;
}
```

Is that possible?
Because in my case, oldThread is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clicked(thread: Thread): void {
    this.newWindow = true;
    if(this.threadService.windows.length === 2) {
        // get the previously opened chat window
       let oldThread = this.threadService.windows[0];            
       this.closeOldThread(oldThread);
    }
    if (!this.thread.isOpen) {
       thread = this.chatService.openThread(thread);
       this.chatService.setCurrentThread(thread);
       this.thread.isOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work either.
When I test my variable (_this.oldThread_) in my if loop (_this.threadService.windows.length === 2_) it is equal to 'undefined' ..

Comment: what is stored in `this.threadService.windows`? object of type `Thread`?

Comment: Thank you very much it works! I had not thought of doing this.